# Why is my chat program code not compatible with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have cloned a code from Github for audio and video chat.When i run the code it is compatible with Mozilla and Edge browser. But the problem is that when i 
try to open it in chrome.it shows an alert telling tht

> you chose not to provide access to the camera/microphone, demo will not work.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767 has your answer but this question is not appropriate for github

Comment: You need to give the site access to your camera and microphone, by clicking the "i" or "lock" symbol at the left end of the browser address bar.

Comment: I gave access to camera and microphone, but still it is not working

Comment: are you testing tablet or phone by anychance? some chrome mobile require additional settings

Comment: nope.I am testing that in PC

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code in chrome, click the area where the secure button usually is. It should be replaced with an I symbol. Click that and allow the microphone and camera. If you don't have a camera, then it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome requires HTTPS for getUserMedia since December 2015. See [here](https://tokbox.com/blog/the-impact-of-googles-new-chrome-security-policy-on-webrtc/) for some details.

Comment: Thank you so much  Philipp. It really helped me a lot but the problem is that I can access the camera through the only tunnel and not everyone can download that to communicate.If there could be a solution to access the camera with IP addresses which are not "https" but "http" it would be really helpful.